# How do I stop ReSharper from placing "x => new" on a new line?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2012, resharper-7.0

I know this is a fairly small detail, but for some reason it's incredibly annoying to me and I cannot figure out how to correct it (I've looked at the "Line Breaks and Wrapping" options).

Here's how I like this code formatted:

```
var reps = ctx.Commissions
    .GroupBy(x => x.SalesRep)
    .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Key.UserID,
                    Name = x.Key.FirstName + " " + x.Key.LastName
                })
    .ToList();
```

ReSharper, though, likes to format it as

```
var reps = ctx.Commissions
    .GroupBy(x => x.SalesRep)
    .Select(
            x => new
                {
                        x.Key.UserID,
                        Name = x.Key.FirstName + " " + x.Key.LastName
                })
    .ToList();
```

Any ideas as to how I can stop ReSharper from doing this?

Thank you,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should disable `Prefer wrap after '(' in invocation` option in `Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping` section.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that option, either way I appreciate your answer. Thank you!